# When I resize, there are gaps between the text?

Tags: media-queries, letter-spacing

When I resize to a smaller screen, the text breaks and there are some gaps between the text. https://github.com/Mr404Found/gatsby-starter-profile-site/issues/1

Comment: Yes, that's what happens when you use `text-align: justify;`.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You have to

```css
text-align: left;
```

Instead of

```css
text-align: justify;
```